# R combine indexed variables into a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have the following variables x11 x12 x13 x21 x22 x23....x51,x52,x53

I would like to have one vector containing all the above values

x <- c(x11,x12,....,x53)

Is there an easy way to combine them into a vector other than typing in all the names individually?

This is just an example, the variable names are indexed but more complex, also there are more than just 5 sets of such variables.

I think all the answers can mitigate this issue. Maybe I should be more clear.

Essentially, there are 2 indices to variable name Xij,

An example is that i ranges from 1-3, j from 1 to 5. So the variables are:

```
X11 X12 X13;
X21 X22 X23;
....;
X51 X52 X53;
```

All the answers can easily apply to each set of Xijs with i=1...5 to create 5 vectors:

Y1 includes values from X11-X13
..
Y5 includes X51-X53.

Then Ys can be combined into Z.

Comment: `x <- paste0('x', 11:53)`? When you say "combine them", do you mean combine the names or the values within the vectors? You probably want a list instead of a vector if it's the latter case.

Comment: The answer probably depends on the details. You should try to make a reproducible example (eg, smaller with just x11-x13). My guess: `unlist(mget(paste0('x', 11:53)))`

Comment: `unlist(mget(ls(pattern ="^x\d{2}$")))`

Comment: `t(sapply(paste0("x",1:5),paste0,1:3))`??? Are those the variables? then do `mget(t(sapply(paste0("x",1:5),paste0,1:3)))`

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend anyone doing this, but you could

```
arr <- c()
for (i in c(11:53)) {
  arr <- c(arr, get(sprintf("x%d", i)))
}
```

Change the range as need.

Answer (score 0):

```
# get all varnames in global environment with name that matches pattern
vars <- ls()[grepl("x", ls())] 

# combine those objects
unlist(lapply(vars, get))
```

Comment: Not familiar with this approach and will give it a try!